# cloudformation stack fails due to resources not creating

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

i'm trying to set up a cloudformation template and somehow it keeps failing like resources declared in the VPC stack are not created

VPC.yaml

```
Parameters:
  VPCName:
    Default: "VPC"
    Type: String
    Description: Name for the VPC

Resources:
  MyVPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: "10.0.0.0/16"
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref VPCName
  MySecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Opening port 80 
      SecurityGroupIngress: 
        - FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          IpProtocol: tcp

  SGPing:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    DependsOn: MyVPC
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: SG to test ping
      VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: 10.0.0.0/24
        - IpProtocol: icmp
          FromPort: 8
          ToPort: -1
          CidrIp: 10.0.0.0/24

Outputs:

  PublicSubnetID:
    Value: !Ref SGPing
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-SGPing"

  MySecurityGroup:
    Value: !Ref MySecurityGroup
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-VPCID"

  Names:
    Value: !Ref MySecurityGroup.GroupId
    Export: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-hui"
```

EC2.yaml

```
Parameters:
  VPCStackName:
    Default: "VPC"
    Type: String
    Description: Name of the VPC Stack

Resources:
  EC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      ImageId: ami-06dd92ecc74fdfb36
      KeyName: aloho
      SubnetId: 
        Fn::ImportValue:
          !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-SGPing"
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - Fn::ImportValue:
            !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-VPCID"

      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: |
          #!/bin/bash
          yum install -y nginx
          echo "Hello from EC2 Instance" > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
```

Error I'm getting:

Embedded stack arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-central-1:114910936230:stack/qwer-EC2Stack2-1VF4VUK57ZJZQ/3a0c09c0-893a-11ee-bad6-0658d296e609 was not successfully created: No export named qwer-EC2Stack2-1VF4VUK57ZJZQ-VPCID found

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting from your stack defined in `VPC.yaml` with the name `"${AWS::StackName}-VPCID"`. Then in your stack defined in `EC2.yaml` you are trying to import using that same name. The problem is that `${AWS::StackName}` is different for each stack. You could use a name for your export without `${AWS::StackName}`, even just a static value like "VPCID", and it would work.